# How do I assign variable to a member of ordered list in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to assign the 4th li child of the ordered list to a variable $target such that it fades out

And this is the jQuery code...just need to set something equals to $target but cant figure out

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var $target = '';
    $target.fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Have you actually tried anything yet?

Comment: Questions here are usually longer than one sentence. Please explain what it is that you're trying to do, post the code you tried, and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: Yes I have tried a few codes but it gives me errors...I just started jquery and cant figure it out.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: _"I have tried a few codes"_. Always a good idea to add that in your question. Helps us know what you're dealing with and see what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ol clas="myList">
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li>HELLO</li>
   <li></li>
</ol>
```

Given the above markup, grab the 4th `li` with the following jQuery:

```
var $target = $('.myList li').eq(3);
$target.fadeOut();
//$target.html() == 'HELLO';
```

Comment: The jQuery set has a 0-based index. So eq(0) is the first element, eq(1) is the second, eq(2) is the third etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you could select the 4th li, I tend to use nth-of-type, but there are lots of ways to [select](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and/or [traverse](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $target = $('li:nth-of-type(4)');
  $target.fadeOut('fast');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

---

For a better experience asking questions here on SO, be sure to check the [relevant documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) before asking.

Answer (score -1):

You don't post any code, so it's hard to see if this is what you want, but I think it is:

```
$target = $('ul').find('li').eq(3);
```

It's self explanatory, but just in case: you first select the list `('ul')`, then you select the items `('li')` and with the `eq(3)` (the fourth item) you finally narrow your search to the element you want.

---

Don't worry about the downvotes. I'm currently receiving them too. It's hard to feel yourself welcome here when you are a beginner, but you will get used to it.

Comment: Thanks for the motivation...I am just a starter but will get used to it